# Why can't muons be the carriers of the strong interaction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

The strong forces operate up to range of $10^{-15}$ meters. The calculations for Muon reveal that they can be propagator for distances up to $10^{-14}$ meters. Why can't I ignore the factor of 10 and call muons the Yukawa particles for short range strong interactions?

Comment: using the same analogy, photons could be mediators of gravitational interaction..but they aren't... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because muons don't carry a color charge, and hence don't participate in the strong interaction...